# Dapper brings datetime field as default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dapper

How come all my searches with dapper bring an empty (default Datetime value) for this workoutdate field?

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

query.Append("SELECT W.WorkoutId, W.Active, W.GymId, W.Spots, W.UserId, W.WorkoutDate, W.WorkoutStatusId FROM [Workout] W");

    public class Workout
    {
        public Guid WorkoutId { get; private set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public Guid? GymId { get; set; }
        public int WorkoutStatusId { get; set; }
        public int Spots { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime WorkoutDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is `WorkoutDate` actually a `datetime` type column?  If it's an `nvarchar`, for example, the casting to datetime may not be successful. If you could provide us with the table definition and the actual Dapper query that would help.

Comment: @pcdev the table definition:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Workout](
 [WorkoutId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [GymId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 [Spots] [int] NOT NULL,
 [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [WorkoutDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 [WorkoutStatusId] [int] NOT NULL,

Comment: and  the in-class field:

        public DateTime WorkoutDate { get; set; }

Comment: and finally the query:
SELECT W.WorkoutId, W.Active, W.GymId, W.Spots, W.UserId," +
                         " W.WorkoutDate, W.WorkoutStatusId, U.FirstName, U.LastName," +
                         " S.SpotterId, S.SpotterImage FROM [Workout] W
INNER JOIN [WorkoutXMuscleGroup] WM ON WM.WorkoutId = W.WorkoutId
INNER JOIN [WorkoutXSpotter] WS ON WM.WorkoutId = W.WorkoutId
INNER JOIN [User] U ON U.UserId = W.UserId
INNER JOIN [Spotter] S ON S.SpotterId = U.UserId
WHERE W.Active = 1

Answer (score 1):

Your column is a datetime2. You can change the way Dapper maps columns like this:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(DateTime), System.Data.DbType.DateTime2);
```

An alternative is to cast it in the select like this:

```
SELECT CAST(W.WorkoutDate AS datetime) ...
```

Or you could change your column to datetime, if you don't need the added precision of datetime2.

Comment: tried both strategies and both of them didn't work =(